# Set height of div equal to another div

Tags: css

[image]

How can we set height of green box equal to the height of red box with scroll in green box. Please note that we cannot set height of red box, it is dynamic and may be changed as content changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/guqfz069/13/

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}


.left{

  background-color: #f00;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right{
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
   
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we might need to throw in some js for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `position` and `absolute` for `.right` you can do that

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


.left{
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right{
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
   
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
    Here is the sample content <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great use of absolute positioning, this is nice

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container>* {
      flex: 1;
    }
    
    
    .left {
    
      background-color: #f00;
      width: 60%;
    
    }
    
    .right {
      background-color: #0f0;
      width: 40%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
    
      </div>
      <div class="right">
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
    
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
        Here is the sample content <br />
      </div>
    </div>
```

DEMO HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/ayL75j4h/

Comment: its the other way around, `.right` should take `.left` 's height and scroll if needed

Comment: You need to set a max-width or a min-height and overflow

Comment: yes, but author says, we cannot add height to `.left`

Comment: So there is no way by CSS

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:auto` to `.left`

```
.left{
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE** 
Based on @Riz's comment
I believe we'll need some js to achieve this

```
const leftHeight = document.querySelector('.left').offsetHeight;
document.querySelector('.right').style.height = `${leftHeight}px`;
```

since `offsetHeight` includes `margin` and `padding`, it'll be better if `box-sizing: border-box` is set

Comment: Height of green box should be changed and match height of red box, green box will have scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS Grid to achieve this effect.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will make a grid with two columns, one for .left, one for .right with the same width & height; The fr (fractional unit) makes sure of that.

Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you add align-items: flex-start and maybe add height: 100%; to child elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use-->> max-height:130px; overflow:auto; -->> in both class left and right,
like this

```
    .left{

  background-color: #f00;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height:130px;
  overflow:auto
}

.right{
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 40%;
  max-height:130px;
  overflow:auto
}
```

and u will get this
[image]

Hope this helped you